# Add .jar to Buildpath but not Classpath within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, buildpath

In this specific case I am creating a Minecraft mod (yea... I know) and to do what I need I am trying to add an external jar (ComputerCraft Mod) to the buildpath, but not have it to the classpath, because Forge (The mod loader) errors on duplicated mods (classes/jars). I believe this is caused by Eclipse automatically adding all the Buildpath classes to the classpath. If there is a setting that I somehow overlooked, or an option for the jar entry, that would be great. Thank you for any info/answers/documentation you are able to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in eclipse -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> In popup window Click "Add External Jar" -> select the jar you want in build path from your machine.

But simply it can stated as

> The classpath is used to find classes when executing a Java program.
>   The build path is used when Eclipse is compiling a Java program.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, that adds it to the classpath. I need it to not be, as it stops the application since two mods are being loaded at the same time. I need to know how to add a jar to the buildpath, but not the runtime classpath

Comment: why don't you remove the jar from the eclipse/mods folder? I simply make a "libs" folder and put all my external jars in there, and then add them as an external jar via project settings.